# GDownloadUrl replacement in Gmap V3

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I want to send and receive data from php files.  What is the best possible way to do this?

What is the best replacement for `GDownloadUrl` in Google Map V3?

Here is my existing function to check if I inserted successfully:

```
function checkSaveGeoFenceData(data,code)
{
    //var geoFenceDataJson = eval('(' + json + ')'); 

    if(code===200)
    {
        //alert("JSON VALUE : "+data+"test");
        if(data=="SMGFE\n")
        {
            alert("Geo Fence " + 
                document.getElementById("geoFenceName").value + 
                " Already Exist");
        }
        else {
            alert("Successfully Inserted");

            window.opener.location.reload();
            window.close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Fail to insert");
    }
}
```

Existing function to grab data from php:

```
function processtViewData(json)
{
    dataJson = eval('(' + json + ')'); 
    var totalData = dataJson.data1.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to GDownloadUrl in the API V3. Loading data via AJAX is a general javascrip task that is not specific to the API or to Google Maps.

Here's a function that will do the same:

```
function ajaxLoad(url,callback,postData,plain) {
    var http_request = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType && plain) {
            http_request.overrideMimeType('text/plain');
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
    if (!http_request) {
        alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }
    http_request.onreadystatechange =  function() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                eval(callback(http_request));
            }
            else {
                alert('Request Failed: ' + http_request.status);
            }
        }
    };

    if (postData) { // POST
        http_request.open('POST', url, true);
        http_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  
        http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postData.length);
        http_request.send(postData);
    }
    else {
        http_request.open('GET', url, true);
        http_request.send(null);
    }
}
```

Make sure your server responds with a `content-type:text/plain` header

Call it with postdsata:

```
var postdata = 'a=1&b=2';
ajaxLoad(serverUrl,myCallback,postdata);



function myCallback(req){
var txt = req.responseText;

// optional, if needed to evaluate JSON
    eval(txt);
}
```

Comment: if I want to send data using post what to modify your ajax codes?

Comment: I will have many variable and value to be send via post but here looks I got only one option or must I put them all into one string separe by &?

Comment: @biz14, yes, you can make the postdata string as long as you need, always separating with &. Otherwise you can try splitting it into different calls.

Comment: @biz14 , by the way, please consider accepting the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: I have update my question with some codes. I will accept your answer but I need two more confirmation one is in my existing checkSaveGeoFenceData I can check if is insert success fully so in your case I got to check via  eval(callback(http_request)); what value will this give me? Next is that how can I parse through the data which I receive from a php script where currently I do via the json method where in the php I add using this method "array_push($data1, array( ... "

Comment: @biz14, eval(callback(http_request)) will give you nothing. Your output to be eval'ed must be plain/text JSON, so you need your PHP scrpt to write a valid JSON structure. It might be best to post a separate question about outputting valid JSON from PHP to be eval'ed in javascript.

Comment: ok I put a separate question on that but without JSON just say that my php echo something can I read via this function you suggested ?

Comment: @biz14,  JSON is JavaScript Object Notation. You only need to use JSON syntax if you want to evaluate objects into your Javascript. Ordinary plain text strings can be read with the function as it is. They do not need to be in a valid JSON format.

Comment: so since I am generating them via this method in my php "array_push($data1, array( ... "  what is the best you suggest for me to read in my ajax function?

Comment: @biz14, I am sorry but I am a disabled person with only one hand. I have done everything I could to put you on the right track, but I cannot write an entire manual for you or you application's code. I have seen the other question you posted. You are still tagging it with google-maps-api-v3, which is not. Using correct tags will get you better help.

Comment: sorry about your condition. I appreciate your help so far and thank you very much though.

Comment: Would you please look at my question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878704/)? I get 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function …' My application uses google's db.Model which I believe is plain text, btw. I am assuming my `readData` is like your `myCallback` but maybe the syntax for `readData` is incorrect (I have tried other syntax, btw). Any help would be appreciated.