# replacing GDownloadUrl in google app engine

Tags: jquery, python, google-maps

**update**
I see now that perhaps I did not include enough of the code for the function which uses GDownloadUrl and have added that below.  In the code if `GDownloadUrl(url, function(doc)` is replaced by  `function ajaxLoad(url,callback,postData,plain)`  what are the variables `callback,postData,plain`? Thanks.

Until Google apps version 3 my [working maps app](http://simplifyconnections.appspot.com/?place=Playground) was being used successfully by a handful of folks. Then a key feature which is triggered my a "singlerightclick" on an existing map pin does not work, and it seems unlikely that Google with fix this problem. So I have been attempting to update the app but am stumped by the decommitted function GDownloadUrl.

Although of late I have become more familiar with using jQuery in another project, and from searching here on stackoverflow.com I gather that jQuery is an alternative to GDownloadUrl, I am at a loss for understanding

1) how to use jQuery here, and

2) more importantly, how to link to the existing data set where legacy users have created map pins using Google's default database with the `class Pin(db.Model)` in the Python code.

Some of my legacy code follows.

```
function process(form) {
    // == obtain the data
    var ID = myArray.length + 1;
    var details = escape(form.data.value);
    var category = parseInt(form.category.value);
    var color = colors[category];
    var label = form.label.value;
    var lat = lastmarker.getPoint().lat();
    var lng = lastmarker.getPoint().lng();
    var url = "details.txt?Action=add&ID=" +ID+ "&lat=" +lat+ "&lng=" +lng+ "&details="+details+"&category="+category+"&label="+label+"&place={{place}}";
    //GLog.write("About to send "+url+ " to the server"); 

    // ===== send the data to the server
    GDownloadUrl(url, function(doc) { 
        });  

    // == remove the input marker and replace it with a completed marker
    map.closeInfoWindow();
    map.removeOverlay(lastmarker);
    var marker = createMarker(lastmarker.getPoint(),details,ID,color,label,0);
    alert("Your information has been processed. You may hover over pushpins to see who others are.");

  }


readData = function(doc) {
        // === split the document into lines ===
        lines = doc.split("\n");
        for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
          if (lines[i].length > 1) {
            // === split each line into parts separated by Tab and use the contents ===
            parts = lines[i].split(String.fromCharCode(9));
            var ID  = parts[0];
            var lat = parseFloat(parts[2]);
            var lng = parseFloat(parts[3]);
            var details = parts[4];
            var pincategory = parts[5];
            var label = parts[6];
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            var pinage = parts[7];
            myArray[i] = new Array(lat,lng,details,point,ID,pincategory,label,pinage);
          }
        }
        // create the marker
        for (var j=0; j<myArray.length; j++) {
          var alat = myArray[j][0];
          var alng = myArray[j][1];
          var adetails = myArray[j][2];
          var apoint = myArray[j][3];
          var ID = myArray[j][4];
          var acolor = colors[myArray[j][5]];
          var alabel = myArray[j][6];
          var apinage = myArray[j][7];
          if(!isNaN(alat+alng)){
            // create the marker
            var marker = createMarker(apoint,adetails,ID,acolor,alabel,apinage);
          }
        }
      }


class Pin(db.Model):
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    lat = db.FloatProperty()
    lng = db.FloatProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    cornerColor  = db.StringProperty(default='ffffff')
    height = db.IntegerProperty(default=32)
    label = db.StringProperty(default='')
    labelColor = db.StringProperty(default='000000')
    labelSize = db.IntegerProperty(default=2)
    primaryColor = db.StringProperty(default='ff0000')
    shadowColor = db.StringProperty(default='000000')
    shape = db.StringProperty(default='circle')
    strokeColor = db.StringProperty(default='000000')
    width = db.IntegerProperty(default=32)
    category = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    scategory = db.StringProperty()
    logindex = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    imageindex = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    deleteRequested = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GDownloadUrl replacement in Gmap V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127035/gdownloadurl-replacement-in-gmap-v3)

Comment: That may well be an answer, but I cannot begin to adapt it to my app without a lot of help. Can you suggest where to read about that background I need, please?

Comment: I have added `ajaxLoad()` to my script. You can see `readData()` in my question. I am getting the error 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ?place=Playground:272
readData ?place=Playground:272
http_request.onreadystatechange ?place=Playground:411`. When I remove the line `lines = doc.split("\n");` from readData, I no longer get the error, but of course my app does not run either. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't know how to use jQuery in your situation, I suggest starting by reading [its documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/).